# How to implement a Walking Zero with atmega328p using pure C and charlie-plexing method?

Tags: c, atmega, avr-gcc, arduino-nano

I want to implement a function thats call "Walking-zero", this supposed to turn all 7 leds and just put one off, and must follow this pattern {1111111, 0111111, 1011111, 1101111, 1110111, 1111011, 1111101, 1111110} where each 1 represents a Led on and each 0 represents a Led off.

Im using {PB0, PB1, PB2, PB3} as my leds output.

So far ive just been able to implement a "Walking-One", which is the oposite of "Walking-Zero".

[this is the code for led_config matrix and ledState()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrEpH.png)[this is the code for playSequence()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTV2I.png) what that does is to keep leds on.

ive tried this:

```
void ledState(uint8_t j)
{
    DDRB &= ~((1<<PB0) | (1<<PB1) | (1<<PB2) | (1<<PB3));
    
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i<7; i++)
    {
                if( i == j)continue; //
        DDRB |= (1<<led_config[i][0] | (1<<led_config[i][1]));
        PORTB |= (1<<led_config[i][0]);
        PORTB &= ~(1<<led_config[i][1]);
    }
}
```

what i tried to do was that if j where equals i, that particular led wont turn on, but the rest should, at least thats what i think, honestly im stuck, any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you configure data direction register on each iteration? It's enough to configure output pins once at startup. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Better upload image with your circuit diagram. Are your LEDs connected as counter-parallel pairs? In this case you can't light two LEDs in a pair simultaneously. You only can get illusion of simultaneous light by fast switching polarity.

Comment: Do you drive the LEDs active high or active low?

Comment: Also why do you keep mucking around with DDRB? If the LEDs are attached to PORTB, then they are attached there kind of permanently and so toggling the port to become an input is nonsense. This might very well be the problem. On some microcontrollers, the GPIO needs some time between DDR and PORT register writes. Not sure how ancient AVR worked in that regard.

Comment: `0x7F ^ (1u << i)`.

Comment: @nielsen Looks like OP control 8 LEDs with 4 pins. So inverting output won't work.

Comment: @dimich Ah, yes, I could only make sense of the first paragraph. It seems it is necessary to look into the linked images to make sense of the rest.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing a [mre] formatted as source. Please add the schematic of the charlie-plexed LEDs, too, and a link to its explanation, as this method is rarely known. -- Your simplest approach would be a separate timer-controlled routine that outputs a bit image of the LEDs' states. Then change the content of this bit image to your liking.

Comment: With charlie-plexing it is possible to statically switch on a single LED, but it is not possible to statically switch on all but one LEDs.